# Await async execution in sync function in webworker (javascript)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, web-worker, synchronous

I know that in the normal dom scope you cannot await a async result in a synchronous function as that would block the UI.

Now, in a webworker it is ok to block the thread. Is there some way there to wait for the async result without using await/async? I am also looking for hacks...

My solution already works fine using await/async/Promise. The reason why I want to avoid await is that I offer the user the possibility to write the code that is executed in the web worker. And as also school children are part of my audience, I want to keep things simple and not have to introduce the whole Promise concept only because they should be able to execute functions that are async.

I want to mimic a sync Api you could say. But in the core of the functions they should call there is async code...

I understand why JS is designed like that, but it feels stupid to me that the system protects me from blocking the thread in a case (web worker) where it would be feasible to block the thread...

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: i think in this case you can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: "*I am aware of the solution to just loop until the result is there*" no it's not. It never is. Not because "*that will use up my CPU*" but because the looping itself (called "busy wait") will take up the thread where you're waiting for something and thus you'd never be able to get it because the thread is busy. You'll probably have to explain why you're trying to avoid `await` which *is designed for exactly your situation*.

Comment: You can use a Promise to execute code when the promise is resolved (the async function completes). Basically 'waiting' for the function to complete by providing the code that needs to be run after the function returns.

Comment: Some usually asynchronous Web APIs are available in a synchronous form in Web Workers (e.g FileReaderSync and XHR), but apart from that no, the fact that the code is ran in a Worker doesn't change how JS works.

Comment: I removed my comment about the busy wait (thankx for the hit) and added my reasoning for asking the question.

Comment: The *other* way to resolve this *as if* it's synchronous is to create synchronous functions and compose them to chain effects but also abstracting away the asynchronicity. Which means that your code wouldn't care about `await`s or `.then()`s or anything like that. However, that also means that higher order functions and concepts like composition, monads, and category theory come into play. Which...is probably less fun for school children. I'd say just let them call an API and tell them to use `await`. It's a bit of magic that makes the code work. That should be enough.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean and post some links @vlaz

Comment: Given your project the best might be to analyse the passed code (AST) and rewrite it yourself, adding the `await`s where needed.

Comment: @LukasLentner this is a good introduction of the subject: https://blog.bitsrc.io/out-with-async-await-and-in-with-promise-lifting-c42882a474fd (the code for the lift function is towards the end of the article under the heading "The Code"). The thing is that lifting is already *automatically* done by the `.then()` method, so in a lot of cases you don't need need separate lifting mechanism. It is worth it if you want to work with multiple different promises at the same time. With that said, Kaiido's idea might be better. Just hide the `await`s by adding them later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with [Atomics.wait](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/wait), [Atomics.notify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/notify) and [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer).

Here is how:

### Enable cross-origin isolation

Set these headers to the html you serve, because SharedArrayBuffer is only available in cross-origin isolated environments thanks to Spectre bug.

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

### Create a main script

which spawns a worker with a doSomething message handler.

```js
const worker = new Worker(new URL("/worker.mjs", location.href));
worker.addEventListener("message", async (event) => {
  console.log("event", event);
  if (event.type === "doSomething") {
    await doSomething();
    Atomics.notify(new Int32Array(event.sab), 0);
  }
});
const doSomething = async () => {
  console.log("doing something...");
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  console.log("did something.");
};
```

Add `<script>` tag to the html to load this.

### Create a worker script

which creates a SharedArrayBuffer and shares it with the main thread, then waits for notification.

```js
console.log("I am a worker");
const sab = new SharedArrayBuffer(4);
postMessage({ type: "doSomething", sab });
Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(sab), 0, 0);
console.log("done");
```

It shows this and waits synchronously for the main thread.

```
I am a worker
```

### The main thread receives the message, do something async, and notify

```
event {
  type: 'doSomething',
  sab: SharedArrayBuffer { [Uint8Contents]: <00 00 00 00>, byteLength: 4 }
}
doing something...
(1s later)
did something.
```

### The worker thread is notified.

```
done
```